# jQuery UI Accordion - Hovering - icon depending on active / default state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hover, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I get the jQuery UI Accordion to display different header-icons depending on the state - active or default?

In the end I want to split this:

> .ui-state-hover

to this:

> .ui-state-default-hover
>
> .ui-state-active-hover

So I can define different background-images for each of these 4 cases:

> .ui-state-default { background-image: url(images/default.png); }
>
> .ui-state-active { background-image: url(images/active.png); }
>   .ui-state-default-hover { background-image: url(images/default-hover.png); }
>   .ui-state-active-hover { background-image: url(images/active-hover.png); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the combination of two css classes:

```
.ui-state-default.ui-state-hover { background-image: url(images/default-hover.png); }

.ui-state-active.ui-state-hover { background-image: url(images/active-hover.png); }
```